# Is this package registered correctly on npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

[UWS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uws) is deprecated, now you can install [μWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js) like so

`npm install uNetworking/uWebSockets.js#v15.10.0`

It gets installed but when you want to update your packages `npm update` you get

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uWebSockets.js - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'uWebSockets.js@^15.10.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-05-29T10_19_50_672Z-debug.log
```

The owner believes it's NPM's fault since he registered the previous package and since you can install the current package using npm why wouldn't you be able to update?

When you search for it on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/), the new package doesn't show, so I wonder how is it possible to install it in the first place if it's not registered and how to fix it without affecting the current users?

Comment: From what I see 15.10.0 is the latest version of that package.
Moreover I can successfuly install this package and then run `npm update` with no problems.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov When you do `npm update` where does ti resolve to?  since `https://registry.npmjs.org/uWebSockets.js` doesn't exist

Comment: Have no idea. But I see no errors and the output is `+uWebSockets.js@15.10.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted npmjs.com, they didn't know why it was happening, nor the owner of the repository.

When Artem Arkhipov commented saying that he did not encounter any errors, I uninstalled and reinstalled the package and everything seem to be working.

If anyone ever encounter this error, please let me know, and I'll tell the owner of the repository how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

1.Install tarball, folder, http url with use npm install
2.Your package name and directory name must be diffrent
3.pheraps you should your keyword name  latter have not capital letter